# Comparison between Stochastic Calculus books

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I am a graduate student and I want to learn stochastic calculus by myself. I have learned measure theory, real analysis, point-set topology and advanced probability theory (David Williams, Probability with Martingales and Kai Lai Chung, A course in probability theory, such as independence, LLN, CLT, discrete-time martingales) before.

The topics that I want to learn include: continuous-time martingale, Brownian Motion, Stochastic Integration, Stochastic Differential Equations, and the general theory on semimartingale.

Now I have seen many answers on the textbooks and I decide to choose books from the following four classics:

Ioannis Karatzas and Steven E. Shreve, Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus

Daniel Revuz and Marc Yor, Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion

Rogers and Williams, Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales, Vol 1&2

Philip E. Protter, Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations

Since time is limited, I cannot learn all these four books. My question is that: what are the differences between these books and which one should I use? Maybe there is no book that covers all the contents, which book should I refer to for each topic?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in the theory of Markov Processes at all? I'd say it's covered in just Rogers&Williams..

Comment: Well.. it s too much to say that RevuzYor does not cover Markov Processes.. But it s definitely not the point of the book..

Comment: I am afraid that I have no idea how many topics the Markov Process theory contains. If Markov Process is one part in Stochastic Calculus theory, then yes.

Comment: I would say that stochastic calculus is *today* a pure martingale theory. But I would also not touch any of these books if you dont have a solid understaing of discrete time Markov Processes.

Comment: I have learned discrete-time Markov Processes in Durrett's books, Probability: Theory and Examples. So it won't be a problem.

Comment: I dont know.. I ll let good mathematicians answer this question.. But be careful: these books are quite hard, not sure they re good to learn the subject. RY is everything the world knows about Brownian Motion, RW is fun to read but for people who already know the subject. KS also very very detailed. P deals mainly with stochastic integration in a general setting but takes a non-classical approach he invented himself..

Comment: Ha ha..Thanks for your useful comment. Maybe I need to find some other texts.

Comment: If you are interested in stochastic integration wrt discontinuous martingales, check out also Cohen & Elliott - Stochastic Calculus and Applications and He, Wang & Yan - Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus. Beware of JacodShiryaev since it s extremely dense (because in that book stochastic integration is only a tool to prove other things)

Comment: Hi if you are not interested in non continuous processes then I would rank Karatzas and Shreve first and then Revuz & Yor book in your list. If you need more than continuity then Protter's book seems a better choice than Rogers and Williams. I may add that the blog "Almost sure" by George Lowther is an incredible source and attains a generality far beyond continuous processes.

Comment: George Lowther's blog is great, another good source! Thanks very muck for your advice.